# Not use current limiting resistor for switching device on off using TIP122 possible?

Tags: power, transistors, resistors, switches

I wanting to control MP3 player and amplifier box through PIC board.

My project is doing announcement when person standing in near PIC board with proximity sensor.

When proximity sensor detecting people, sending signal that processing by PIC board.

Now from PIC I want turn on (person present) or off (person not present) the MP3 player and also the amplifier box connected to MP3 player output and speaker.

I thinking using cheap 5A BJT like TIP122 to turn on and off the MP3 player and also the amplifier box?

Now amplifier box requiring 30V @ 2.5A, so if I need put current limiting resistor for switching TIP122, then that resistor rating calculating as:

```
R = (30 - 1)V/ 2.5A = 11 Ohm
Wattage = (I**2) * R = (2.5**2) * 11 = 68.75W
```

This very big resistor impossible for purchasing!

**I thinking if possible to completely not use current limiting resistor for switching TIP122 at all?**

If this possible, then **base of TIP122 connect to PIC pin** and **TIP122 in series with amplifier box power supply path sink**.

Is this workable and reliable design (not want burn TIP122)?

Comment: Please check the Comment

Comment: Where are you in India?

Comment: Here's a [list of franchised Indian distributors for a number of US components sellers](http://www.cirrus.com/en/contacts/dist/country/IN.html).Includes Avnet, Digikey, Mouser, Farnell ... .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon None of those distributors will deal with an individual with retail requirements, by the way. The only recourse is to buy whatever the nearest electronics market street will sell you, at whatever price they will quote: Power MOSFETs are available, but you don't want to know the mark-ups. :-) The TIP122 on the other hand is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a series resistor. Think of the transistor as a switch.

You do need a base drive resistor from the PIC.

BUT use a MOSFET - it will do a better job than the TIP122 and will cost no more.

Rushing out. Look at www.digikey.com. Search for MOSFET N Channel, set filtersto 100V min and say 10A and search based on lowest price in stock in 1's.

More later maybe ...

Comment: Nice I not need resistor :-)

I need more explain why MOSFET better?

Comment: @SGhosh I reason which I see that could make a FET better is that BJT's conductivity is controlled by current going into its base. A microcontroller may not be able to directly supply current required for full conductivity of the transistor, which would complicate the design and you may be required to limit current going tout of the microcontroller too. With FETs the conductivity is controlled by voltage and almost no current goes into the gate.

Comment: Can PIC control any FET? From comment by 'Saneesh A T', I see only logic level can be, and they not available from shop in India, but TIP122 is. I calculating base current as 20mA to drive 2A Ic as beta = 1000+ for TIP122?

Comment: The TIP122 will work.  Use 470 ohms in series with the base. Power dissipation will be about 1.0V * 2.5A. (1.0V being the saturation voltage from the datasheet @2.5A) 2.5 watts means you should have a heatsink on the transistor.

Answer (score 2):

Rating of your amplifier box is 30V @ 2.5A, which means the system will draw a maximum of 2.5A of current when it is connected to a 30V supply. You can just use a BJT, MOSFET, or Relay of rating > 2.5A for this purpose.

Comment: I need more explain why MOSFET better? Also relay more expensive and more parts than BJT.

Comment: If you use a low side MOSFET you don't need much components. Logic level MOSFETs are also available which is logic level compatible, and can be easily controlled with your micro controller.

Comment: What is low side MOSFET? Logic level MOSFETs not available from shop in India, but TIP122 is. I calculating base current as 20mA to drive 2A Ic as beta = 1000+ for TIP122?

Comment: If you are comfortable with your design, you may proced with it, it will be quicker for you. The IRF540 can be used with microcontroller, and is commonly available. But i agree, smaller foot print MOSFETS are not commonly available. For N channel MOSFET low side means, the load is connected between the Drain and VCC, and the MOSFET is used to switch the Ground. If you connect the load between Source and GND, you may need a large voltage to maintain Gate-Source Voltage of the MOSFET.

Comment: I not comfortable with my design as I not sure if beta = 1000+ for TIP122 can be assuming to hold across all batch. Also how beta changing with temperature and how I calculate how much temperature rise of TIP122 because of Ic = 3A?

Comment: The beta of the transistor never be >1000. I am not sure but i think it is around 100. It can be simply solved by using a darlington pair, or simply using a normal transistor, and connect the output of the normal transistor to the power transistor. The heat generated depends many factors and is not simple to calculate. You can solve all of these problems by using a MOSFET instead.

Comment: @SaneeshAT the TIP122 is a Darlington transistor, and it has a beta of > 1000 at high currents.